# Proof explanation that $p: S^n \to \mathbb{R} P^n$ is an open map.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I'm reading a certain Topology textbook and having trouble understanding the claim. The map $p$ sends each element of $S^n$ to a straight line (that passes through origin) induced by a unit vector. The following argument supposedly proves that  $p$ is open

> If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ that doesn't contain antipodal points $\{x, -x\}$, then $p(U\cap S^n)$ is open, because its preimage in the set $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ is open.

The space $\mathbb{R}P^n$  has the coinduced topology, so the set is open if and only if its preimage is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$. I also think that $S^n$ has the subspace topology, that is, every open set looks like $U\cap S^n$  for some open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. I can't see through the argument at all. Why does the proof take an open set that doesn't contain antipodal points? Whether or not we take antipodal points, the image will be the same. Further, how can we say that the preimage (of canonical projection) of $p(U\cap S^n)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$? I cannot really say anything about the preimage.

Comment: What does it mean for a line to be induced by a unit vector?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I think the "unit vector" is just a point $x \in S^n$ and the induced  line the unique line through $0, x, -x$ in the surrounding Euclidean space.

Comment: As Henno Brandsma has explained in his answer, it is irrelevant whether or not antipodal points are excluded. But excluding antipodal points has a benefit. If  $V \subset S^n$ is open and does not contain antipodal points, then $p : V \to p(V)$ is an open continuous bijection, i.e. a homeomorphism. This shows that $p$ is a covering map with two sheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have $U \cap S^n$ as an open subset of $S^n$, then the preimage $p^{-1}[p[U \cap S^n]]$ is just $(U \cup -U) \cap S^n$ (we add all the antipodes of $U$ really) which is again open (as $x \to -x$ is a homeomorphism of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ and of $S^n$ too). I don't see the point in excluding antipodal points in $U$ at the start, and I think it's not needed.